# ajax submit gif

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery.form plugin, I don't think my ajax loading gif placed a right selection in jQuery. Following are my codes, could someone tell me how to place the loading gif correctly.

Many thanks.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact-form").validate({

        // .......

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                url:"echo/vali.php",
                type:"POST",
                success: function(){
                    $('#loader').css('visibility','visible');
                    $('#contact-form').hide();
                    $('#sent').show();
                    $('#loader').css('visibility','hidden');
                }
            });
        }
    });  
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="loader"> <img src="images/loader.gif" width="18" height="18" / >
```

CSS:

```
#loader{
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    position:relative;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I see is that your HTML, as posted, is malformed. If you want the GIF to be inside of the `#loader` div, you need to make sure you close your tag:

```
<div id="loader">
  <img src="images/loader.gif" width="18" height="18"/>
</div>
```

If that's not the issue, have you checked to ensure that your `#loader` div displays correctly with its initial `visibility` set to `visible`?

**Edit**:

Another big issue is that you're only showing the loader *after* the form was posted successfully — `$('#loader').css('visibility','visible');` is in the success callback. Try changing your JS to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact-form").validate({

        // .......

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#loader').css('visibility','visible');
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                url:"echo/vali.php",
                type:"POST",
                success: function(){
                    $('#contact-form').hide();
                    $('#sent').show();
                    $('#loader').css('visibility','hidden');
                }
            });
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: thank you Jacob, I forgot to paste </div>. It works! Got it worked :-). Thanks again for your help.